Is there a way to write the following SQL query?
I am using Apache Superset connected to Elasticsearch data via elasticsearch-dbapi, when I SELECT * from some indexes, I get the following error:
elasticsearch error: TransportError(500, 'ql_illegal_argument_exception', 'Arrays (returned by [decision.certification.comments.user.sn]) are not supported')
When I search the documentation for this error, it is suggesting setting this field_multi_value_leniency to true.
Suggested solution from ES documentation
My question is how can I add this line to my SQLQ query inside the SQL Lab query section of Apache Superset?
Thank you.
